# Different labels for the x-axis

Tags: r, plot, stripchart

i have this data and plot

```
mydata <- data.frame(a=c(1:5),b=c(6:10),c=c(11:15),e=c(16:20))
plot <- stripchart(mydata, method="jitter", vertical=T,main='plot',pch=19)
```

I would like to subset the x axis into two labels named 'a+b' and 'c+d' labels

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "subset the x axis"? what do you want the result to look like? Do you want to merge a and b, to show a common label in-between a and b or, in addition to the already existing a and b labels, to add a 'a+b' label below?

Comment: Take a look at the `axis` function.

Comment: @plannapus "or, in addition to the already existing a and b labels, to add a 'a+b' label below?" --> exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can simply use `mtext` on side 1:

```
mydata <- data.frame(a=c(1:5),b=c(6:10),c=c(11:15),d=c(16:20))
plot <- stripchart(mydata, method="jitter", vertical=T,main='plot',pch=19)
mtext(c('a+b','c+d'),side=1,line=3,at=c(1.5,3.5))
```

Argument `line` is to set up the vertical position and `at` the position on the x-axis.

**Edit**: To add a distance between the two groups, you can do like this (there may be a cleaner way to do that but that's the only one I can think of from the top of my head):

```
mydata <- data.frame(a=c(1:5),b=c(6:10),c=c(11:15),d=c(16:20))
plot <- stripchart(mydata, method="jitter", vertical=T, main='plot',pch=19, 
                   at=c(1,2,4,5),xlim=c(0,6))
mtext(c('a+b','c+d'),1,line=3,at=c(1.5,4.5))
```

Argument `at` of `stripchart` is the one to fiddle with, but you then have to modify the plot limits (`xlim`)  and the x-value at which you write the axis label (in `mtext`).

Comment: Is there a way to make the distance between a and b and c and e shorter than the distance b and c?